# asp net web application under IIS 7.5 redirect to a login page but gives error http 404.0 after log-in

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5

I have a application developed using ASP NET MVC and I have configured a virtual direcotry in IIS.

I can access the server folder and also my app located in http:localhost:8081/application

I am redirect to a login page located /Account/Login as expected but when I log in using my username/password I am getting an Erro HTTP 404.0 - Not Found.

Why this behavior?

**Edit:**

**Controller:**

```
    //
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        MembershipProvider mp = Membership.Provider;

        if (ModelState.IsValid && mp.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Username ou Password incorreto!.");

        return View(model);
    }
```

**RouteConfig:**

```
namespace tgpwebged { public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I found the problem. No clue how to solve though. When I try to access /home/index my app redirects to /Account/Login if the users is not authenticated. http://localhost:8081/tgpwebged/ After the user logs-in it should redirect to http://localhost:8081/tgpwebged/Home/Index but no, IIS is changing the url to http://localhost:8081/Account/Login. Where is the 'tgpwebged' part of the URL?

Comment: Login Page is not able to navigate to next page mentioned in your login page code when the aunthentication is true. Can you please share login page code

Comment: For debugging purpose, after loggin just change the url in the address bar to your homepage url  and check whether its getting rewritten

Comment: After login, If I try localhost:8081/Home/Index IIS still can´t find because there is no Physical Path S:\Projects\Home\Index. But if I mannualy put localhost:8081/tgpwebged/Home/Index I am redirected again to http://localhost:8081/tgpwebged/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2ftgpwebged%2fHome%2fIndex (Login Page). After login, IIS should locate the physical files in a different physical path S:\Projects\tgpwebged\Home\Index. Should I change IIS settings or my ASP.NET app?

Comment: Asp.Net is working fine and as expected. I am not sure about your IIS settings and authentication. There might be some code written somewhere else also which might be responsible for this redirection.Do you any redirection logic written anywhere else?

Comment: no. Its is a fresh IIS install and a standard asp.net mvc app.

Comment: Found the awnser:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621401/error-404-0-after-login-asp-net-mvc-and-iis-7-5

Comment: Found the awnser

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621401/error-404-0-after-login-asp-net-mvc-and-iis-7-5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not with my asp net app, but with the IIS configuration.
Guys in charge of IIS fix the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you web.config should include the virtual directory in it's `loginUrl1` attribute.

Try changing your web.config like this:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="tgpwebged/Account/Login"  />
</authentication>
```

Comment: I changed to <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="frmLogin" loginUrl="~/tgpwebged/Account/Login" protection="All" path="/" timeout="30" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="false" />. I don´t see any changes
    </authentication>

Comment: No don't add the `~`. Try it without the tilde and no path like my code. If that doesn't work just `<forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login"  />` again with no path.

Comment: look at that: Requested URL http://localhost:8081/Account/Login
Physical Path S:\Projects\Account\Login. The requested url nor the physical path does not change.

Comment: Let me ask somenthing. IIS authentication is set to allow anonymous and form authentication only. Is that right? Also logon url for form authentication is set to  tgpwebged/Account/Login

Comment: When I first access, as in IIS logon url is set to tgpwebged/Account/Login it has no problem to find the log in page. When submitting the form for authentication where I can specify its path? does not matter if I change the web.config file as you said I am still been redirected to localhost:8081/Account/Login which is not where it should be. Should go to localhost:8081/tgpwebged/Account/Login.

Comment: Also I can see that: Logon Method Anonymous
Logon User Anonymous after try to login in the error page