# Error 404.0 after login. Asp.Net MVC and IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5

I have a ASP.NET MVC app running over IIS 7.5 .
Forms Authenticated enabled

I can access the login page. (Which means that route is ok) but when I log in the app should send a post data to `http://localhost/tgpwebged/Account/Login` to authenticate the user.

The problem is that my application is looking for /Account/Login in `http://localhost/Account/Login` (This is not the path).

I am trying without success change this behavior.

This is my **route.config**

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

**web.config**

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="Account/Login"/>
</authentication>
```

**View**

```
<form method="post" action="/Account/Login">
```

Also IIS is set to accept Anonymous login for users to be able to access the login page.

This is the error message I am getting:

TTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

**Some detailed information:**

Requested URL   `http://localhost:8081/Account/Login` (right path: `http://localhost:8081/tgpwebged/Account/Login` )
Physical Path   S:\Projects\Account\Login (Should be S:\Projects\tgpwebged\Account\Login)
Logon Method    Anonymous
Logon User  Anonymous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The POST is going to wrong URL because that is what you have mentioned in the view. See

```
<form method="post" action="/Account/Login">
```

This would always post to `<host name>/Account/Login`

Try to give either relative path (or substitute absolute path using ResolveUrl method) - for example, in aspx view, you can use

```
<form method="post" action='<%= this.ResolveUrl("~/Account/Login") %>' >
```

In razor (cshtml) view, you can try (untested)

```
<form method="post" action='@Url.Content("~/Account/Login")' >
```