# Deploy MVC4 on IIS7.5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, iis-7.5

I deployed an MVC4 application developed using framework v4.5 on IIS 7.5.
The application works fine on IISExpress, but not on IIS7.5.
When I try to access the application on my machine at: `localhost/ClienteDigital.Web/` I'm redirected to login page, but at the wrong address, `localhost/Account/Login/`.
If I force the right address, `localhost/ClienteDigital.Web/Account/Login/` the page is displayed, but when I enter the login and password, it won't redirect to Home. The login page reappears.
I'm almost sure that the problem is some IIS configurations, and not in the application.

I'm using integrated pipeline and have enabled only Anonymous and Forms Authentication on my IIS application.

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13620095/asp-net-web-application-under-iis-7-5-redirect-to-a-login-page-but-gives-error-h/14191129#14191129) Guilerme Longo said that he solved the problem, but he didn't say how.

Anybody have any idea?

Comment: Can you post your code to the Login Action and the login view?

Comment: I found the problems.

First was a wrong code (not coded by me, but I should have checked Foot in Mouth): There was a filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/Account/Login"); instead of filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("~/Account/Login");

Second was only set Enable 32-Bit Applications to True. It's necessary because of Oracle.DataAccess library.

Thanks.